# How can I make an Azure Logic App only execute during a certain window of time?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've got a logic app that runs every 15 minutes. I'd like to make it only run every 15 minutes between the hours of 8 AM and 4 PM, but I'm unable to figure out how to go about that.
My understanding thus far is that I can't add that condition to the Recurrence, which is set to `15 minutes`, and that I'll probably have to make it so that `every 15 minutes, if time is between 8 AM and 4 PM, do x`... but I'm still struggling to figure out if I ought to be using the "Get current time" feature and using a conditional comparator - if this is the case, how do I make the comparison?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you achieve it in using Recurrence trigger itself. As shown below I have it for every 5 minutes on Monday to Friday between 8 am to 7 pm

[image]

You can also go through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/concepts-schedule-automated-recurring-tasks-workflows) for any additional details